# How to connect Ms. Sql server with php

Tags: php

I'm try to connect my php with Ms. Sql sever and I'm using mssql_connect(). But it can't connect. I find many solution and some said

remove ';' 
extension=php_mssql.dll in php.ini
ntwdblib.dll
php_mssql.dll

both insert already restart 
and Fatal error: Call to undefined function mssql_connect()

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the [MS SQL Client Tools](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mssql.requirements.php)?

http://php.net/manual/en/book.mssql.php

Answer (score 0):

what OS are you running? have you installed the php-mssql package?

[php.net/manual/en/mssql.setup.php](http://php.net/manual/en/mssql.setup.php)

after you install you will need to restart Apache